# Madgwick sensor fusion on LSM9DS0

Tags: accelerometer, quaternions, gyroscope, sensor-fusion

I'm trying to implement Madgwick sensor fusion algorithm [from here](http://www.x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/) on LSM9DS0 sensor (accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer) on STM Cortex M3 microcontroller.

Raw data from all sensors seems to be fine.

My problem is: when I hold sensor with it's z-axis horizontal or downwards (i.e. roll or pitch angle is more than 90 degrees) - quaternion from filter becomes really unstable and randomly flips 180 degrees.
More correctly, q0 and q3 are constantly changing signs, resulting in 180 degree flip of rotation.

I tried using constant values instead of real sensor output and still got this behavior.

When z-axis is more or less vertical, quaternion seems plausible.

I haven't seen anything like this on example videos.

I tried to ignore magnetometer data and use 6DOF version of filter but it was a disaster; quaternion is just flying around and spinning uncontrollibly.

I have to set beta-parameter quite large (~100) because lesser values have given very shaky result with sudden flips. I do find this strange since usually beta is about 0.5-0.05.

Filter update frequency is 1KHz.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/madgwick-imu-ahrs-and-fast-inverse-square-root?id=705844%3ATopic%3A1018435&page=4#comments) is said that there is a mistake in code of madgwick filter!

Gradient decent step should look like this:

```
s0= -_2q2*(2*(q1q3 - q0q2) - ax)    +   _2q1*(2*(q0q1 + q2q3) - ay)   +  -_4bz*q2*(_4bx*(0.5 - q2q2 - q3q3) + _4bz*(q1q3 - q0q2) - mx)   +   (-_4bx*q3+_4bz*q1)*(_4bx*(q1q2 - q0q3) + _4bz*(q0q1 + q2q3) - my)    +   _4bx*q2*(_4bx*(q0q2 + q1q3) + _4bz*(0.5 - q1q1 - q2q2) - mz);
s1= _2q3*(2*(q1q3 - q0q2) - ax) +   _2q0*(2*(q0q1 + q2q3) - ay) +   -4*q1*(2*(0.5 - q1q1 - q2q2) - az)    +   _4bz*q3*(_4bx*(0.5 - q2q2 - q3q3) + _4bz*(q1q3 - q0q2) - mx)   + (_4bx*q2+_4bz*q0)*(_4bx*(q1q2 - q0q3) + _4bz*(q0q1 + q2q3) - my)   +   (_4bx*q3-_8bz*q1)*(_4bx*(q0q2 + q1q3) + _4bz*(0.5 - q1q1 - q2q2) - mz);             
s2= -_2q0*(2*(q1q3 - q0q2) - ax)    +     _2q3*(2*(q0q1 + q2q3) - ay)   +   (-4*q2)*(2*(0.5 - q1q1 - q2q2) - az) +   (-_8bx*q2-_4bz*q0)*(_4bx*(0.5 - q2q2 - q3q3) + _4bz*(q1q3 - q0q2) - mx)+(_4bx*q1+_4bz*q3)*(_4bx*(q1q2 - q0q3) + _4bz*(q0q1 + q2q3) - my)+(_4bx*q0-_8bz*q2)*(_4bx*(q0q2 + q1q3) + _4bz*(0.5 - q1q1 - q2q2) - mz);
s3= _2q1*(2*(q1q3 - q0q2) - ax) +   _2q2*(2*(q0q1 + q2q3) - ay)+(-_8bx*q3+_4bz*q1)*(_4bx*(0.5 - q2q2 - q3q3) + _4bz*(q1q3 - q0q2) - mx)+(-_4bx*q0+_4bz*q2)*(_4bx*(q1q2 - q0q3) + _4bz*(q0q1 + q2q3) - my)+(_4bx*q1)*(_4bx*(q0q2 + q1q3) + _4bz*(0.5 - q1q1 - q2q2) - mz);
```

and that code on official site is outdated and soon will be replaced.

Correcting this produced a satisfying result.

My other mistake was not reading function prototype properly. I copied slightly changed version of the code, where accelerometer and gyroscope values were interchanged.